# Why was __proto__ replaced by the functions getPrototypeOf/setPrototypeOf?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I just want to know what was the main reason behind replacing `__proto__` with the functions `getPrototypeOf/setPrototypeOf`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[MDN explains it pretty well.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

> The use of `__proto__` is controversial and discouraged. It was never originally included in the ECMAScript language spec, but modern browsers implemented it anyway. Only recently was the `__proto__` property standardized by the ECMAScript 2015 specification for compatibility with web browsers, so it will be supported into the future. It is deprecated in favor of `Object.getPrototypeOf/Reflect.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf/Reflect.setPrototypeOf`.

`Object.getPrototypeOf` and its variants have been fully defined by the specification since engines have implemented it. `__proto__` has not, so it shouldn't be considered reliable in older environments that may happen to have something like `__proto__`.

[Another reason why it might have been deprecated](https://javascript.info/prototype-methods#very-plain) is that it allows for the changing of the prototype via syntax that *looks* like it's just assigning a plain property to an object, when in fact, if the property is `__proto__`, is invoking a setter and changing the internal prototype of the object. This is not desirable behavior, and can be a security vulnerability - but, some sites still use `__proto__`, so environments can't remove the functionality without breaking those sites, so they won't. But it can still be marked as deprecated.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why they didn't just go with `__proto__` and preferred add yet a new way in the standards

Comment: @Kaiido because the inclusion of `__proto__` was non-standard, they could behave differently within different implementations. It's easier to introduce a new standard API than to standardize an existing non-standard API with potentially inconsistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts hum not really no. Living standards are just made of that: One vendor implements new stuffs, an other one follows, then specs are written based on the "standard" behavior. When it is found that implementations differ, then there is a discussion to check which of the implementations or specs should be edited to match the actual "standards".

Comment: Probably partly because `__proto__` is inherited from `Object.prototype`, so it's almost impossible to use it for custom-prototyped objects, and can be shadowed. I don't even know if `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__').get.call(myObject)` works?

Comment: Just because living standards _can_ happen that way doesn't make the process any easier. My point still stands. In any case the original browsers that introduced `__proto__` are no longer maintained, so any discussion to determine what behavior should be matched would be moot seeing as the original implementation will never change.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Because in the case of `__proto__` there were real drawbacks compared to the alternative. It is in no way because it was already implemented before the specs were written.  And my comment was asking for CertainPerformance to dig up these drawbacks, which they just did. (and FZs has an other one: the fact it's inherited from Object.prototype.

Comment: ...(cont) its addition also led to many security vulnerabilites in libraries, allowing prototype pollution attacks to happen.